# $\epsilon - \delta$ proof of $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} x^x = 1$

Tags: calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

How to prove it by epsilon-delta proof instead of l'Hôpital's rule？I do not know how to choose delta in this case.

Comment: It's not "instead of". Any limit you prove, by whatever method, is by "epsilon-delta". It's just that usually we don't explicitly use it in the proof. But it is always implicitly used in whatever theorems were using. We can always rewrite any proof with the $\epsilon-\delta$ terminology explicit.

Comment: First, Use Mathjax. Second, what's your try ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\log$ and $\exp$ are continuous functions, that is the same as proving
$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}x\log x = 0,$$
or, by replacing $x$ with $e^{-t}$,
$$ \lim_{t\to +\infty} -t e^{-t} = 0 $$
that is trivial since $e^t>1+t+\frac{t^2}{2}$ for any $t>0$.